# How to make an image stretch to VH and/or VW (actually stretch)

Tags: javascript, velo

Basically I have a decorative background image which I want to constantly stretch to the background of the site. No cropping or care given to aspect ratio. Is there a custom velo code for this?

Hoping for a plug and play solution. Will buy coffee.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit, `object-fit: fill;`

Comment: <img src="path/to/image.jpg" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw; object-fit: cover;">

Answer (score 0):

---

Full page background in 2 lines of css.

```css
body {
   background-image: url("https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/SO_Announcement-1200x675.png");
   background-size: cover;
}
```

---

If you want it to stretch so, whole image can is visible, then:

```css
body {
   background-image: url("https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/SO_Announcement-1200x675.png");
   background-size: 100% 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced the URL with my image url, but nothing seems to be happening - image attached. Much appreciated. https://ibb.co/M5FMg8v

Comment: wait, from the screenshot, are you putting this into a js file?

Comment: Unsure... I'm pasting directly into Editor X's dev mode

Comment: okay then try pasting this `(()=>{let a = document.createElement('style'); a.innerHTML='body { background-image: url("https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/SO_Announcement-1200x675.png");   background-size: 100% 100vh;}'; document.body.appendChild(a)})()` to the same place. btw try opening console by pressing ctrl+shift+j and pasting it and pressing enter will turn this page's background to the image too!